# Apache Camel: How to Create and Delete WMQ Queue When the Application Run and Stop

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq

currently I am working with Apache Camel and what I need to do is create a WMQ Queue in camel (Something like session queue) when I start the application and the delete it when I stop the application. Is there any possible way?

Or, I have checked that the apache camel will create a temporary with random name when I create a connection factory. is there any ways to change the name of the temporary queue from random name into static name?

FYI, for now I am usign Spring for my Component Configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this does not have anything to do with Apache Camel actually, as it can be seen as any JMS client application with respect to this issue.

IBM WebSphere MQ have two types of queues.

- Regular queues that needs to be created (and possibly deleted) by an administrator, script or the like.
- Temporary queues, where the name is irrelevant, it has to be unique in the context of the queue manager. JMS does not allow naming of temporary queues since the name is actually irrelevant since it should be used once and then discarded.

WMQ is not really designed to behave in a way to support your usecase.

The only option is to figure out if you can somehow automate the task of create/remove queues. That is usually done manually in a MQ Explorer/MQSC/MQMON or similar tools. Other MOM software such as ActiveMQ does such things automatically.

There are probably several ways to create queues remotely. One is to use [PCF commands](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/docs/V7.0/csqzac07.pdf) which you may send to queues like SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE. However, that queue is usually very well protected in an enterprise setup so that only administrators can use it. You have no information about that in your question, however. Another option (not nice, but non the less), is to let an application on the queue manager server (maybe camel?) invoke runmqsc with params to create a queue.